# Tez crashes on Hadoop-2.5.2 cluster

Tags: java, apache, maven, hadoop, hive

I successfully Build Tez-0.6.0 against Hadoop-2.5.2

Then I configured Tez-0.6.0 as like in http://tez.apache.org/install.html

Moved Tez lib package to HDFS location and updated my **tez-site.xml**

```
 <property>
    <name>tez.lib.uris</name>
    <value>${fs.default.name}/apps/Tez/,${fs.default.name}/apps/Tez/lib/</value>
  </property>
```

After that I tried the sample test for tez

```
hadoop jar tez-examples-0.6.0.jar orderedwordcount <input> <output>
```

But I face following error while running this command

```
Running OrderedWordCount
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Hadoop/
share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBind
er.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Tez/lib
/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
15/04/15 10:47:57 INFO client.TezClient: Tez Client Version: [ component=tez-api
, version=0.6.0, revision=${buildNumber}, SCM-URL=scm:git:https://git-wip-us.apa
che.org/repos/asf/tez.git, buildTime=2015-04-15T01:13:02Z ]
15/04/15 10:48:00 INFO client.TezClient: Submitting DAG application with id: app
lication_1429073725727_0005
15/04/15 10:48:00 INFO Configuration.deprecation: fs.default.name is deprecated.
 Instead, use fs.defaultFS
15/04/15 10:48:00 INFO client.TezClientUtils: Using tez.lib.uris value from conf
iguration: hdfs://HA-Cluster/apps/Tez/,hdfs://HA-Cluster/apps/Tez/lib/
15/04/15 10:48:01 INFO client.TezClient: Stage directory /tmp/app/tez/sta
ging doesn't exist and is created
15/04/15 10:48:01 INFO client.TezClient: Tez system stage directory hdfs://HA-cluster
/tmp/app/tez/staging/.tez/application_1429073725727_0005 doesn't ex
ist and is created
15/04/15 10:48:02 INFO client.TezClient: Submitting DAG to YARN, applicationId=a
pplication_1429073725727_0005, dagName=OrderedWordCount
15/04/15 10:48:03 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_14
29073725727_0005
15/04/15 10:48:03 INFO client.TezClient: The url to track the Tez AM: http://syn
cserver34:8088/proxy/application_1429073725727_0005/
15/04/15 10:48:03 INFO client.DAGClientImpl: Waiting for DAG to start running
15/04/15 10:48:09 INFO client.DAGClientImpl: DAG completed. FinalState=FAILED
OrderedWordCount failed with diagnostics: [Application application_1429073725727
_0005 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1429073725727_0005_00000
2 exited with  exitCode: -1073741515 due to: Exception from container-launch: Ex
itCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
ExitCodeException exitCode=-1073741515:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:538)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:455)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:
702)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.la
unchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:195)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:300)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.C
ontainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:81)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.
java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor
.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

        1 file(s) moved.

Container exited with a non-zero exit code -1073741515
.Failing this attempt.. Failing the application.]
```

While Seeing at Resourcemanager log:

```
15/04/15 12:56:15 ERROR scheduler.SchedulerApplicationAttempt: Error trying to a
ssign container token and NM token to an allocated container container_142908227
1173_0001_01_000001
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.UnknownHostException: MasterNode
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.buildTokenService(SecurityUti
l.java:373)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.utils.BuilderUtils.newContainerToken(Bu
ilderUtils.java:247)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.security.RMContainerTok
enSecretManager.createContainerToken(RMContainerTokenSecretManager.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.SchedulerAppl
icationAttempt.pullNewlyAllocatedContainersAndNMTokens(SchedulerApplicationAttem
pt.java:425)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.common.fica.F
iCaSchedulerApp.getAllocation(FiCaSchedulerApp.java:248)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.Capa
cityScheduler.allocate(CapacityScheduler.java:736)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAtte
mptImpl$AMContainerAllocatedTransition.transition(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:816)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAtte
mptImpl$AMContainerAllocatedTransition.transition(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:809)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$MultipleInternalArc.
doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:385)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.doTransition(StateMa
chineFactory.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory.access$300(StateMach
ineFactory.java:46)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachineFactory$InternalStateMachine
.doTransition(StateMachineFactory.java:448)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAtte
mptImpl.handle(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:649)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.rmapp.attempt.RMAppAtte
mptImpl.handle(RMAppAttemptImpl.java:104)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$Applica
tionAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager$Applica
tionAttemptEventDispatcher.handle(ResourceManager.java:742)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher.dispatch(AsyncDispatcher
.java:173)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.event.AsyncDispatcher$1.run(AsyncDispatcher.ja
va:106)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: MasterNode
        ... 19 more
```

Problem might be while connecting to nodemanager it unable to handshake with ResourceManager.

If I try in single node hadoop cluster mean It working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add property

> yarn.nodemanager.delete.debug-delay-sec
>   1200

One thing while running the "launchcontainer.cmd" located in hadoop \tmp..\appcache location.It arise an issue in accessing the Dll for running mapreduce on windows platform, ie MSVCR100.dll is missing to handle the Tez job.As bellow

> "The program can't start because MSCVR100.dll is missing from your 
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this issue"

Provide Full privilege to hadoop-tmp directory and try to replaced/Moved msvcr100.dll(C:\Windows\System32) file in windows machine to run the mapreduce program for TEZ job.